# Why do I have to install pymongo after pybson (=bson, GitHub:py-bson) to get pybson imported successfully?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pymongo, bson

+++

EDIT: Long time after putting the question online I noticed that this is a spin-off of [Can't connect to MongoDB 2.0.5 database with pymongo 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603754/cant-connect-to-mongodb-2-0-5-database-with-pymongo-2-2) which says that you have to install bson before you install pymongo. I am asking here not for this already known solution, but for the *reason* of this needed install order. And I add a small thing, I am installing "bson" module as "pybson", which makes it possible to distinguish the `import bson` name clash of the two packages.

+++

I am using a workaround to avoid the name clash of pymongo's bson module and bson's (py-bson on GitHub) bson module: I am installing bson package as pybson, see https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/70.

From the answer at [pip install of eve package installs bson and pymongo which breaks pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484316/pip-install-of-eve-package-installs-bson-and-pymongo-which-breaks-pymongo/54485721#54485721), we get the main idea:

> `pymongo` doesn't bring `bson` as a dependency, it just has its own
> `bson` implementation. The problem is `pymongo` installs its `bson` as
> a top-level directory in `site-packages/` thus overwriting any
> existing `bson` there.

But this does not explain why the install order [1. bson, 2. pymongo] solves the issue, instead you would expect it to be exactly the other way round!

In my case, I have installed a new system, using anaconda as the base. I had installed bson using `pip install pybson`, and it said:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> import pybson # same as bson
>
> File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybson_*init*_.py", line 23, in 
> from .objectid import ObjectId
>
> File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybson\objectid.py", line 30, in 
> from bson.py3compat import PY3, bytes_from_hex, string_type, text_type
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bson'

After installing pymongo in addition to pybson, using `conda install pymongo`, the `import pybson` statement worked. Why?

Comment: This appears to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485721/13986717

Comment: @119631 It is the link that was already mentioned in the question :) "pip install of eve package installs bson and pymongo which breaks pymongo" but you are right of course

Comment: This is also related [Name clash of two different bson modules - How can I use both pymongo's bson module and bson's bson module in the same script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068007/name-clash-of-two-different-bson-modules-how-can-i-use-both-pymongos-bson-mod/63068008#63068008).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoted idea of the question must be put the other way round: `pip install bson` after `pip install pymongo` disturbs pymongo's bson dependency so that pymongo's bson module will not work anymore. It is probably not because bson overwrites pymongo's bson dependency, but rather because of the name clash: both packages use the same bson module 'bson', and that causes the same effect as if bson overwrote pymongo's bson.

Strange enough: you *have* to install pymongo in addition to (py)bson, as the question states. That hints at bson using the bson dependency of pymongo in its own package.

As installing bson with `pip install bson` *after* `pip install pymongo` will disturb pymongo's bson, see [Can't connect to MongoDB 2.0.5 database with pymongo 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603754/cant-connect-to-mongodb-2-0-5-database-with-pymongo-2-2), we can assume that there is a name clash between the two bson modules which is dominated by the one that is installed as the last. It seems as if the (py)bson package needs a dominating pymongo bson dependency in addition to its own bson module, and (py)bson imports the pymongo dependency as `import bson` in its internal scripts, *even though it has the bson module itself*. I do not know whether the domination is caused by overwriting, or whether this is just a problem of the python environment. The former is more likely, since the order of installs (first `pip install bson`, afterwards `pip install pymongo`), becomes irrelevant as soon as you install bson with `pip install pybson` instead of `pip install bson`, see [pip install of eve package installs bson and pymongo which breaks pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484316/pip-install-of-eve-package-installs-bson-and-pymongo-which-breaks-pymongo/63067801#63067801).