# Name clash of two different bson modules - How can I use both pymongo's bson module and bson's bson module in the same script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pymongo, bson

How to avoid the name clash of pymongo's bson module and bson's (py-bson on GitHub) bson module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ***bson*** package as ***pybson***, see https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/70.

I have used

`pip uninstall bson`

and

`pip install pybson`

now so that I can use

`import pybson as bson`

when I want the old name back. If I accidentally need both ***pymongo***'s and ***pybson***'s `import bson`, I can use aliases.